# "Expires" caching headers for static content in _layouts and the Style Library

Tags: publishing-site, caching

Is it possible to set *Expires* caching headers for static content in `_layouts` and the *Style Library*?

Currently, each page request generates about 100 requests for static content like CSS, images and JavaScript, each resulting in a *Not Modified* response from the server. But these 100 requests are having an impact on the perceived performance of the site.

I have static content deployed to both `_layouts` (non-modifiable content) and the *Style Library* (modifiable content). Some of this content is themes for jQuery components, some is custom JavaScript, some is images used for with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same question myself and when I get some time I plan on looking at [Disk Based Caching for Binary Large Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa604896.aspx). If you do give it a try it would be good to hear how it worked.

Comment: Actually, this works quite nicely. Enabling the SharePoint BLOb cache and setting the `max-age` to something did the trick.

Comment: @ScarePoint how did you set the "max-age", directly in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You would add max-age directly in the web.config of the IIS site for the SharePoint site in the